# How to start and stop gif images in android

Tags: android

In my application i want to play gif images i am able to play gif images but i want to handle gif images like if i click start button animation should start and if click stop button  animation should stop.

```
     strtbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(mBitmap);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        if (mMovie != null) {
            int dur = mMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }
            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, mBitmap2.getWidth() - mMovie.width(),
                        mBitmap2.getHeight() - mMovie.height());
      //                invalidate();
            Log.i("movie",""+mMovieStart);
            Log.i("jjhjhhnjhj",""+mMovie);
        }
    }
```

please help me how to start and stop gif animated images.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android19Animation.php

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

Find out images which you want for animation. They should be in sequence so that we can realize it as flipping continuously. File type of images like GIF, PNG etc. After finding, copy them and place them by copy and paste in

"Your project" -> res -> drawable-mdpi -> paste images

Drawable has three categories

```
hdpi-> high dots per inch
ldpi->large dots per inch
mdpi->medium dots per inch
```

Step 2

There are two methods to perform this animation. 1) By creating "BitmapDrawable" objects, 2) By creating "animation" xml file. We will see both method one by one.

Do with "BitmapDrawable"

```
Syntax:

BitmapDrawable object=(BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.<image_name>);

Example

Suppose I have image named "sample.png" in "res.drawable" directory, then



 BitmapDrawable frame1=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample);


 AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();

Now, we can add frames which we have created above as like you want.

Syntax:



 AnimationDrawable.addFrame(BitmapDrawable,duration);

Example



 animation.addFrame(frame1,1000);

In this animation, while you start this animation, it will stop after last added frame. If you like to continue this animation, following method must be implemented.
```

animation.setOneShot(false);

```
Now, bind "ImageView" object of layout



  ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);   



    animation.start();
    animation.stop();

Description:
    Duration is in milliseconds.
    setBackgroundDrawable(animation) method will set background with animation and give control over animation.
    start() method will start your animation and stop() will stop this animation.

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list
      xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
      android:oneshot="false">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/sample1" android:duration="50"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/sample2" android:duration="50"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/sample3" android:duration="50"/>
    </animation-list>

In above code, I have added 3 frames with "android:drawable" attribute and duration in milliseconds.

Now, bind "ImageView" object with layout and implement following methods.



  ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageBitmap(null);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);

Next, create object of "AnimatinDrawable" and give background to "AnimationDrawable" so that it can handle it.



  AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
    animation.start();
    animation.stop();
```

Using "BitmapDrawable"

Main.java

```
package com.animationapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationAppActvity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageView img;
    Button btnStart,btnStop;
    AnimationDrawable animation;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int duration = 150;
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        BitmapDrawable frame1 =
            (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d1);
        BitmapDrawable frame2 =
            (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d2);
        BitmapDrawable frame3 =
            (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d3);       

        animation = new AnimationDrawable();       
        animation.addFrame(frame1, duration);
        animation.addFrame(frame2, duration);
        animation.addFrame(frame3, duration);

        animation.setOneShot(false);

        img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  animation.start();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             animation.stop();
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<ImageView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:minHeight="191px" android:minWidth="285px">
</ImageView>
<Button
      android:text="Start"
      android:id="@+id/btnStart"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<Button
      android:text="Stop"
      android:id="@+id/btnStop"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using "animation.xml" file

```
package com.AnimApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView; 

public class AnimAppActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      Button btnStart,btnStop;
      ImageView img;
      AnimationDrawable animation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation);
        animation=(AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   animation.start();
              }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            animation.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/d1" android:duration="50"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/d2" android:duration="50"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/d3" android:duration="50"/>
</animation-list>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i am using images with .gif i want to start and stop gif images not .png