# How to stop gif animation in Android?

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif

I'm using the below class. How do I stop and start looping based on click events? I tried removing invalidate(), but Gif doesn't start loading at all.

**GifView class**

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.example.merchant.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class GifView extends View{

private InputStream gifInputStream;
private Movie gifMovie;
private int movieWidth, movieHeight;
private long movieDuration;
private long movieStart;

public GifView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}


public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    setFocusable(true);
    gifInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ani_bart);

    gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);  
    movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
    movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
    movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
}

public int getMovieWidth() {
    return movieWidth;
}

public int getMovieHeight() {
    return movieHeight;
}

public long getMovieDuration() {
    return movieDuration;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if(movieStart == 0) {
        movieStart = now;
    }

    if(gifMovie != null) {

        int dur = gifMovie.duration();
        if(dur == 0) {
            dur = 1000;
        }

        int relTime = (int)((now - movieStart) % dur);

        gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

        gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add a `boolean` field to the class - e.g., `private boolean isPlaying;` -  check it first thing in `onDraw()`, and `return;` if it's `false`. Create public methods to start and stop, setting the field appropriately in each, and then call `invalidate()` at the end of the start method.

Comment: Can you tell me the code I should use in stop method, when I want to end the animation?

Comment: `isPlaying = false;`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to overcome the issue. Not really sure however if this is a valid solution. Worked for me though.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
        mMovieStart = now;
    }

    if (gifMovie != null) {

        int dur = gifMovie.duration();
        if (dur == 0) {
            dur = 1000;
        }
        now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
        if (now - mMovieStart > movieDuration) {
            relTime = 0;
        }

        gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

        gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        invalidate();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's not possible
But if you need to control plying you can create frme aniation in android via [animation-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406540/how-to-start-and-stop-gif-images-in-android)